# Creating Logical Volume Partition Type with parted

Tags: partitioning, lvm, parted

I am trying to create a `logical volume partition` using `parted` and so I used the following steps:

1. Create partition with `parted` using the interactive mode which would translate to:

   - `mkpart`, then
   - Gave the start and end
   - Then ran `set 1 lvm on` to flag that partition as lvm (but I see lsb)
2. Tried to create a physical volume with command:

   ```
   sudo pvcreate /dev/sda4
   ```

I get the error: `device /dev/sda4 excluded by a filter`, then I ran the `pvcreated` command with the options `-vvvv` and I see the error:

```
skipping too small to hold a pv
```

I now ran `fdisk` on `/dev/sda` and I see the `/dev/sda4` partition information as:

```
/dev/sda4:=> id:f, Type: W95 Ext'd(LBA)
```

This is different from the information for the other logical volume partitions I have, which is:

```
/dev/sda3:=> id:8e, Type: Linux LVM
```

Now the new LVM partition `/dev/sda4` is approximately the same size as the other so why can't I create a physical volume. How does one create a logical volume partition using `parted` as opposed to `fdisk`.

Comment: See this for more info: Full-system encryption with manual control and dual-booting Paddy Landau
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2357627

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `on` :-/